# Chrome image rendering issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, google-chrome, firefox

We are developing an image viewer with zoom and cet...We are developing with angular js and using matrix3d transformations on the images so we can manipulate them.
When opening our project with Firefox with 30 1MB pics it renders them quite easily, while in google chrome it makes problems with even 4 1MB images. I feel Like we are missing a few css lines which will solve it all.
What might be the causes for this kind of thing?

Comment: what is the problem and where is the code/

Comment: can you explain your problem with Plunker, so it would be easy to understand and debug.

Comment: It's a really complicated and long code. Can it be the angular code?